# Use Express session in Ejs from one route to another

Tags: express, ejs

I'm working on simple application where home page list the possible hotels. You can click on it and it will display more information on clicked hotel. I'm using Express and Ejs for implementing this application.

What I did is, I created one `nav.ejs` and this navigation contains following links:

1. Home
2. Offers
3. Signin
4. Logout

But, these `Offers` and `Logout` links will only display if user logged in successfully otherwise it will hidden and same is true for `Signin`. I implemented following in `sign-in.js` routing:

```js
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var exe = `SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?`;
    dbConn.get(exe, [username, password], (err, rs) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Facing problem while finding users');
        } else {
            if (rs) {
                req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
                res.locals.isLoggedIn = true;
                res.redirect('/');
            } else {
                req.flash('err', 'incorrect credintials.');
                res.render('sign-in')
            }
        }
    });
});
```

You can see over there, I'm creating a session and also saving the value in locals as well.

```js
req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
res.locals.isLoggedIn = true;
```

In `nav.ejs` file, I have written,

```
<nav>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <% if (locals.isLoggedIn == true) { %>
        <a href="/offers">Offers</a>
        <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
    <% } else { %>
        <a href="/sign-in">Sign-in</a>        
    <% } %>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

`res.locals` does not persist to the next route.  The `res` object applies ONLY to this particular request.  Only `req.session` will be preserved for future routes for that user.  You will have to re-assign `res.locals` in the next route before you call `res.render()` in that next route.

So, when you do this:

```
            req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
            res.locals.isLoggedIn = true;
            res.redirect('/');
```

`res.redirect('/')` sends a response to the browser.  That request is now done. 
 Then the browser processes the redirect and makes a NEW request to the server for the `/` route.  The value of `res.locals` you just set will be gone when the new `/` route gets hit after the redirect is processed by the browser.

So, in all routes where you want to use the session data in the rendered template, read data from `req.session` and set `res.locals` appropriately for the template you're about to render.

Comment: @kiran - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure.  If this didn't answer your question, please comment about which part of your question you're still confused about.